# Индексирование текста на Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Программа должна принимать много строчек текста, удалять в нем слова из stopWords и сокращать на -ing , -ed, -ly оставшиеся слова если они не находяться в noStemWords. Потом выводить частоту нахождения слов в тексте в виде: слово : строчка#, строчка#,...
http://pastebin.com/aL341xG9
Я осилил создание словаря, но не могу понять как из этого словаря вытянуть каждый лист и повыкидывать из него stopWords и отредактировать окончание каждого слова не трогая noStemWords. И я могу использовать только strip(), split() и стандартные функции для листов и словарей

Comment: Если информация необходима для ответа, то поместите её прямо в ответ. Не используйте внешние ресурсы. Если это учебное задание (из-за странных ограничений), то не помещайте всё задание в один Stack Overflow вопрос—попробуйте сузить проблему до конкретного шага, который у вас не получается. Если необходимо, то задайте несколько (самодостаточных) вопросов—не публикуйте весь код без разбора: создайте минимальный но полный пример кода, который демонстрирует специфичную проблему для каждого вопроса. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Про Python не подскажу, но вот [пример на Ruby](https://gist.github.com/psylone/0185d6df994c55929011b7e5f1131697).

Основаня идея в предварительной обработке текста и построении [обратного индекса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81).